# Try to understand std::enable_shared_from_this<T> but cause a bad_weak_ptr using it

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I try to understand the behavior of std::enable_shared_from_this class, but I cant understand it.
So I've write a simple program to test different situations.

### Question

Can someone explain me the behavior of the following code, because I can't explain the observed result.

Thanks for you help.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct C : std::enable_shared_from_this<C> { };

int main () {
    {//test 1
    std::shared_ptr<C> foo, bar;
    foo = std::make_shared<C>();
    bar = foo->shared_from_this(); //ok
    std::cout<<"shared_ptr : ok"<<std::endl;
    }

    {//test 2
    std::shared_ptr<C> foo = std::shared_ptr<C>(new C);
    std::shared_ptr<C> bar;
    bar = foo->shared_from_this(); //ok
    std::cout<<"shared_ptr + New : ok"<<std::endl;
    }

    {//test 3
    C* foo = new C;
    std::shared_ptr<C> bar;
    bar = foo->shared_from_this(); //throw std::bad_weak_ptr
    std::cout<<"New : ok"<<std::endl;
    }

   {//test 4 (should make a invalid free of something like that)
    C foo;
    std::shared_ptr<C> bar;
    bar = foo.shared_from_this();//throw std::bad_weak_ptr
    std::cout<<"local : ok"<<std::endl;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
shared_ptr : ok
shared_ptr + New : ok
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
   what():  bad_weak_ptr
```

### Build Informations

- System : Windows 7 x64
- Compiler : mingw 4.9.2 x64

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The contract for `enable_shared_from_this` is that it will provide a `shared_ptr` when you call `shared_from_this()` **if** the object is managed by a `shared_ptr`. It cannot create a `shared_ptr` by itself if it is not already being managed.

You already figured out in the last test case why it would be a bad idea to allow `shared_from_this()` to create a shared pointer for you...

Comment: Thank for you reply. I now understand the observed behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly from the original boost documentation, "There must exist at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns t".  For cases 3 and 4 there isn't at the point you call shared_from_this().